# undecorate function names with visual studio sdk

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, visual-studio-addins, name-mangling

To undecorate mangled C++ names that Visual Studio generates, you can use `undname.exe`.

But what if you want to avoid the overhead of creating a full-blown process every time you need undecoration?
Is there any equivalent functionality in the Visual Studio SDK (should be supported in VS2005)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for [`UnDecorateSymbolName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681400%28VS.85%29.aspx) function provided by dbghelp.