# How to undecorate name from decorated name?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, name-mangling

[At a post of Raymond Chen,](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/29/9255240.aspx) he seems to be able to know the function's undecorated name from the decorated name. I have no idea how could he do this.

In this decorated name,

> ?GetName@PushButton@UILibrary@@UAEPB_WPAPAVStringHolder@2@@Z

What does the each component mean?

Comment: Consult your implementation's documentation or play a bit around with a demangler and learn the most common patterns.

Comment: The answer is in the blog. "We ask the undname program". With a little training you could read such names yourself, just generate a few decorated names from sources you know, but the complete rules are complex (as the c++ type system is complex) and it is not worth discovering and learning them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1617204/471164

Comment: Does this answer your question? [undecorate function names with visual studio sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617204/undecorate-function-names-with-visual-studio-sdk)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To avoid guessing, and still not really use tools, the [`UnDecorateSymbolName` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681400%28VS.85%29.aspx) may be of use. I would hope that gives an authoritative correct answer.

To do it manually, [this page](http://mearie.org/documents/mscmangle/) has some information on the scheme, as do [these](http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/msvc/language/decoration/index.htm).

The basic outline is `_name@scope@scope@@parameters@something@@something`. I suspect the last two parts are stack size and calling convention or similar, but the documentation likely has more detail.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the link. Much complicate than I expected, though -_-;

Comment: The biggest chunk (name and containing scopes) is pretty simple, just listed in reverse order. Apparently the prefix is pretty well documented, and I have seen (but can't find) the scheme for the parameters.

Answer (score 7):

Name mangling is compiler dependant.

In the article you linked, Raymond is using an MS util (undname) to remove the mangling.

[Here is a table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#How_different_compilers_mangle_the_same_functions) showing how common compilers mangle.

Comment: With the `visual-studio` tag, the question is also compiler dependent, and this doesn't help answer it at all.

Comment: Yes I saw that, but I feel he could demangle the name by himself at the last simple example. Okay, then isn't there no way to guess it easily?

Comment: @peachykeen: `undname` is a Microsoft tool, and as such tightly bound to Visual Studio. I don't see the problem with this answer.

Comment: There are rules, like ? is followed by a name of a member function, @ means a scope, T, U, V are followed by a union, struct, class names, other letters mean builtin types - if you are really interested, just generate a few mangled names from declarations you know and you will soon learn the basic patterns used.

Comment: @Benjamin: There is a simple way to guess: experience. The mangling of a particular compiler is fixed and defined. After some time looking at mangled and unmangled names you can recognize common patterns and won't need to look at the docs every time.

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft Visual Studio comes with a undname.exe tool.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms937379.aspx

If you have MS VS at a default location you can use:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\undname.exe" ?GetName@PushButton@UILibrary@@UAEPB_WPAPAVStringHolder@2@@Z
>
> Microsoft (R) C++ Name Undecorator
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Undecoration of :- "?GetName@PushButton@UILibrary@@UAEPB_WPAPAVStringHolder@2@@Z" is :- "public: virtual wchar_t const * __thiscall UILibrary::PushButton::GetName(class UILibrary::StringHolder * *)"